# Magento2: Is it safe to run command for enable cache on production mode?

Tags: magento2

Is it safe to run commands for enable cache on production mode?
As we don't have option to enable cache in admin.

Any suggestions

Thanks

Comment: Yes Its safe you can run that command :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes its safe, no issue with that command, and i suggest to always enable cache

Answer (score 1):

There is no harm to enable cache in production mode. You can use below command to enable it.

Enable or disable cache types
This command enables you to enable or disable all cache types or only the ones you specify. Disabling cache types is useful during development because you see the results of your changes without having to flush the cache; however, disabling cache types have an adverse effect on performance.

Starting in version 2.2, you can only enable or disable cache types using the command line while running Magento in production mode. If running Magento in developer mode, you can enable or disable cache types using the command line or manually. Before doing so, you must manually make /app/etc/env.php writeable by the Magento file system owner.

You can clean (also referred to as flush or refresh) cache types using either the command line or the Magento Admin.

Command options:

bin/magento cache:enable [type] ... [type]

bin/magento cache:disable [type] ... [type]

Where omitting [type] enables or disables all cache types at the same time. The type option is a space-separated list of cache types.

To list cache types and their status:

bin/magento cache:status

For example, to disable the full page cache and the DDL cache:

bin/magento cache:disable db_ddl full_page

Sample result:

Changed cache status:

```
   db_ddl: 1 -> 0
full_page: 1 -> 0
```

Please accetp this answer if it's useful for you.
Thanks